# Is it possible to stop or interrupt a main thread by a subthread (started from a notification handler) by signals, events,... in Windows

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, exception, notifications, signals

I have not much knowledge about signals, exceptions and threads. I found a lot of answers, but none yet for me as it seems to be a special case.

I would like to stop the main thread by a subthread without polling. I thought of some kind of expections, but I found out that they are localy to the thread. Signals can only be triggered by the main thread and events seem to wait for the "event" (synchronisation feature)...

The subthread is a device notification, so the function in the subthread is automatically called from a device:

h = plc.add_device_notification(variable,                                       pyads.NotificationAttrib(sizeof(pyads.PLCTYPE_BOOL)), function_f())

The best solution would be for me, if the exception would be globally and could be caught in the main (like keyboardinterrupt).

Comment: Hi, I was able to stop the main thread from the subthread by: os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT),.... this is nice, so now it would be fine to be able to catch the exception.... Best regards, Matthias

Comment: This seems to be a solution: use "os.kill(os.getpid(), signal.CTRL_C_EVENT)" . Then an exception can be caught in the main thread to restart the test.... Best regards Matthias